# How to center a square div in middle of two columns in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two columns in a row with `col-6` and a jumbotron this is my code:

```
  <div class="jumbotron text-left" style="background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/gradient1.jpg); background-size: cover;">
      <h1>Test</h1>   
    </div>          
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">        
    <div class="col-md-12">        
    <p class="text-center square">TEST</p>        
    </div>        
    </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit </h3>           
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h3>test</h3>        
        </div>   
      </div>
    </div>
```

And this is my styling:

```
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #9FB6A6;
  border-radius: 3px;  
}
```

And this is what I wanna achieve:

[image: Sketch]

What I have tried:

I have used the `text-center` class and `z-index`. The problem is I can't get the square div over the jumbotron like in the sketch.

Here you have a jsfiddle so you can see the behaviour:

https://jsfiddle.net/rmjy5pch/

Can somebody point me in the right direction?

Comment: links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by the code in the question itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using absolute positioning like this

https://jsfiddle.net/oqyzsxc3/3/

```
<body>

<div class="jumbotron text-left" style="background-image: url(https://mdbootstrap.com/img/Photos/Others/gradient1.jpg); background-size: cover;">
  <h1>Test</h1>

</div>

<div class="container-fluid position-relative">
  <div class="square-container text-center">
    <p class=" square">TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <h3>test</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #9FB6A6;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.square-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: -60px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to add `margin:0 auto;` to the `.square`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. The square is now centered now I want to overlap between the 2 (jumbtron and the under row) how can I move the square a little bit up? I have tried margin bottom and padding bottom.

Answer (score 0):

```
.square {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: #9FB6A6;
  border-radius: 3px; 
  margin: -20px auto 0;
}
```

Try adding margin:0 auto to the square class?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your time. The square is now centered now I want to overlap between the 2 (jumbtron and the under row) how can I move the square a little bit up? I have tried margin bottom and padding bottom.

Comment: You can give a negative top margin like so: margin: -20px auto 0; I've updated the answer with this now

Answer (score 0):

Using HTML and CSS

```css
.root{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background:white;
    border: 0.5px solid black;
    position: relative;
}
.second{
    display:flex;
}
.first{
    height:120px;
    border-bottom: 0.5px solid black;
}
.second div{
    flex: 1;
    height:120px;
}
.centerTex{
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    background: red;
    color:white;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius:2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="first">
   Jumbotron
  </div>
  <div class="centerTex">Test</div>
  <div class="second">
  <div>Col -6</div>
  <div>Col -6</div>
  </div>    
  </div>
```